# Serana's location for follower recruiting after Dawnguard quest. 

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

After you dismiss Serana, she tells you she'll be waiting for you at the Glade, I went to the Ancestor Glade, but I can't find her [maybe I missed her]. :S Is this not the glade she was referring to?

After trying out one of the answers, I still couldn't find her. DO NOTE that the dawnguard quest has been completed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Were you doing the mission where you had to go there? Have you tried casting Detect Dead to see if she's hiding somewhere? If you aren't doing that mission, she will either be at the vampire castle or at Fort Dawnguard, depending on which faction you chose to help; sometimes she will mistakenly say the glade line after you complete that mission, but she will still return to the base.

Comment: unfortunately I tried this and it didn't work after dawnguard's quest. It works immediately after she's cured from vampirism. But after that, I can't find her anywhere.

Comment: Well, that's strange. Are you playing on PC?

Comment: Yea, I'm playing PC (trying to avoid using console commands)

Comment: player.moveto 02002B74 will move you to where she is. If that doesn't work try 01002B74 or 03002B74.

Comment: Well, where was she?

Comment: I can't seem to find her anywhere on my xbox

Answer (score 1):

I found her sleeping at a small camp just outside of the glade!

Answer (score 0):

check castle volkihar where you enter the soul cairn i found her their mixing potions along with al the supplies restocked only after a few days of waiting